# Room. NullPointer. Дефолтное значение дб

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arch, room

Использую Room+LiveData+Dagger2
db

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(MonthlyBudget::class, Purchase::class), version 
= 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
   abstract fun budgetDAO(): BudgetDAO
   abstract fun purchaseDAO(): PurchaseDAO
```

вот метод в dagger2 который провайдит db

```
    @Provides
fun providesAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "my-budget-db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
```

Метод в даггер на который ругается.

```
 @Provides
@Singleton
@Named("CurrentMonthBudget")
fun provideCurrentMonthBudget(repository: AppRepository): MonthlyBudget = repository.currentMonthBudget()
```

а вот inject этого объкга

```
 @Inject
@Nullable
@field:Named("CurrentMonthBudget")
lateinit var currentMonthBudget: MonthlyBudget
```

Из за того, что база данных пуста вылетает

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method

Что нужно сделать заполнить бд дефолтными данными? есди да то скажите как сделать лучше всего?Или есть просто более умный способ?

### UPDATE 1

Пока реализовал так в класс создания бд добавил проверку и в добавление каких то данных дефолтных

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(MonthlyBudget::class, Purchase::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun budgetDAO(): BudgetDAO
abstract fun purchaseDAO(): PurchaseDAO
companion object {
fun getInstance(context:Context):AppDatabase{
    val database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "my-budget-db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
    if (database.budgetDAO().queryCurrentMonthBudget() == null){
        database.budgetDAO().insert(MonthlyBudget(0), MonthlyBudget(0))
        database.purchaseDAO().insert(Purchase("default",0))
    }
    return database
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, Dagger не предназначен для работы с БД, т.е. его можно и нужно использовать для создания `AppDatabase`, чтобы провайдить и инжектить `DAO` классы, но не для получения самих данных.

```
@Inject
@Nullable
@field:Named("CurrentMonthBudget")
lateinit var currentMonthBudget: MonthlyBudget
```

Вот тут вам нужно инжектить `BudgetDAO` или `AppRepository`, и потом уже у них вызывать метод `queryCurrentMonthBudget()` и проверять есть ли данные.

Во-вторых, исправьте метод `providesAppDatabase` на:

```
@Provides
fun provideDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "my-budget-db").build()
}
```

Здесь не стоит использовать single-expression function, кроме того, `allowMainThreadQueries` тоже не стоит использовать, т.к. этот метод разрешает запросы к БД в основном UI-потоке, что может привести к зависанию интерфейса - почитайте про асинхронные запросы.

Чтобы предзаполнить БД данным, можно повесить callback на её создание:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "my-budget-db")
    .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO 'table_name' etc....")
            }
    })
    .build()
```